# how to use and install arbotix_gui on ubuntu20 and ros neotic?

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython, ros, raspberry-pi4

First of all, thanks for help.
I read lots of pages for how to install arbotix_gui on ubuntu, and tried a lot, but I always get failure, the message was as below after I executed "arbotix_gui":

---

```
/opt/ros/noetic/bin/arbotix_gui:203: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Using deprecated class PySimpleApp. Use :class:`App` instead.
  app = wx.PySimpleApp()

/opt/ros/noetic/bin/arbotix_gui:73: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  wx.StaticLine(self.movebase, -1, (width/2, 0), (1,width), style=wx.LI_VERTICAL)

/opt/ros/noetic/bin/arbotix_gui:74: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  wx.StaticLine(self.movebase, -1, (0, width/2), (width,1))

/opt/ros/noetic/bin/arbotix_gui:125: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item __call__. Use :meth:`EvtHandler.Bind` instead.
  wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.onClose)

/opt/ros/noetic/bin/arbotix_gui:126: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item __call__. Use :meth:`EvtHandler.Bind` instead.
  wx.EVT_TIMER(self, self.TIMER_ID, self.onTimer)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/ros/noetic/bin/arbotix_gui", line 204, in <module>
    frame = controllerGUI(None, True)

  File "/opt/ros/noetic/bin/arbotix_gui", line 126, in __init__
    wx.EVT_TIMER(self, self.TIMER_ID, self.onTimer)

  File "/home/techmarvel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 82, in deprecated_func
    return item(*args)

  File "/home/techmarvel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 1557, in __call__
    assert len(args) == 2 + self.expectedIDs

AssertionError
```

---

1. the ros is running on a raspberry pi 4B, it is ubuntu18.04.5 and ROS Melodic
2. ubuntu20.04.2 and ROS noetic are running on laptop virtual machine.
3. raspberry pi is confirgured as master, and laptop is confirgured as host.
4. I connect from laptop to raspberry pi, and roslaunch by SSH.it is done by the user on raspberry pi.
5. check rostopic and start rviz on laytop side. it is done by the user on virtual machine.
6. then I try arbotix_gui by the user on virtual machine.
7. what I want to do is move the robot by arbotix_gui, and see the result in rviz.

I follow the installation steps from "http://wiki.ros.org/arbotix"
the "arbotix_gui" file is from the installation "sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-arbotix".

there are 2 different ways of installation on the ROS web page, another is :"git clone [https://github.com/vanadiumlabs/arbotix_ros.git"](https://github.com/vanadiumlabs/arbotix_ros.git%22). I get a folder by this way, and it could be copied into a ros work space and "catkin_make".

Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried raising an issue on the github?

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you install / clone the package in your catkin workspace?
Are you using the right version of python?

Comment: I didn't ask this question on github, I will try it. I didn't see any error when I catkin_make in the workspace folder, everything was displayed in white, no red, no orange. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a full answer, since it was resolved in the comments (I think).

The apt servers can be behind in updates to packages, and small differences in development environment can cause unexpected failures. When in doubt, try building or running the source code in isolation, checking the versions of python or ros or dependencies that you're using, and if it persists, submit a minimum reproducible example (build+run steps) in the github repo for that package. That will be the quickest way to get real support or bugfixes, if & only if you've identified it as not an issue caused by you.

Comment: I found something else, and testing now, let's see if the problem could be solved. probably it is because I don't know how to use it correctly. appreciate for help.

Comment: I got a video for how to use arbotix, but it was a different way by command, not GUI. I will keep looking for the solution. if I find how to correctly use the software, I will post it here. thanks for help.